# Spring Session: Update Logged in user object in redis immediately

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-session

I have two web applications (A and B).
The first web application (A) is used as a reverse proxy using spring-cloud.
I'm using spring-session to store the sessions in a redis database for both applications.

**The problem**
When I modify a field (e.g name) of the current (logged in) user, the current logged in user object is not updated immediately and as a result, when I'm trying to retrieve current logged in user in a next call (via @AuthenticationPrincipal) I get a non-updated user object.

My custom user details object:

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends my.package.User implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails, java.io.Serializable { 
// ...
}
```

How can I update the current user object immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've had the similar issue and I resolved it in the following manner:

1.Created a custom  Authentication class

```
public class MyCustomAuthentication implements Authentication {

    private UserDetails userDetails;

    public MyCustomAuthentication(UserDetails userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public Object getDetails() { return userDetails; }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() { return userDetails; }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() { return true; }
    ...
 }
```

2. update userDetails object with some fresh data (I guess, 'name' in your case)
3. Set new authentication created from userDetails in SecurityContextHolder

   ```
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new MyCustomAuthentication(userDetails));
   ```

Hope you will find that helpful.